# tests.php issue - sipp webfrontend

Tags: php, mysql, apache, centos6

I'm trying to install a PHP based application called sipp webfrontend on a centos 6.5 server.

I think I have met all of the following requirements:

- LAMP Environement (Linux, Apache, Mysql, PHP)
- At least 0.5MB free disk space
- A valid MYSQL user with privileges to create a database and tables
- Write access in or beneath apache's www subfolder, or at least one of its subfolders (directly or via FTP, SSH ...)
- At least one version of SIPp installed

But when I point my browser at the URL I get the following:

`. * * * * END LICENCE * * * * */ header("location: tests.php"); ?>`

I see nothing in the httpd.log file.

Does anyone know what maybe going wrong here?

The code

```
    ?
/*
 * SIPp Webfrontend - Web tool to create, manage and run SIPp test cases
 * Copyright (c) 2008 Mario Smeritschnig
 * Idea, support, planning, guidance Michael Hirschbichler
 *
 * * * BEGIN LICENCE * * *
 *
 * This file is part of SIPp Webfrontend.
 * 
 * SIPp Webfrontend is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 * 
 * SIPp Webfrontend is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 * 
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with SIPp Webfrontend.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 *
 * * * END LICENCE * * *
 *
 */

// Here the user gets an overview of existing tests and can sort or remove them.

session_start();
require_once "authentication.php";
require_once "db.php";
require_once "dbHelper.php";
require_once "helper.php";

$action = $_GET["action"];
$id = $_GET["id"];


// manage ascending and descending sortable colums
if($_GET["sort"] != "") {
    if($_SESSION["s_sort"] != $_GET["sort"]) $order = "ASC";
    else {
        $order = $_SESSION["s_order"];
        if($order == "ASC") $order = "DESC";
        else $order = "ASC";
    }
    $_SESSION["s_order"] = $order;
    $_SESSION["s_sort"] = $_GET["sort"];
}

// define default sort parameters
if($_SESSION["s_sort"] == "") $_SESSION["s_sort"] = "name";
if($_SESSION["s_order"] == "") $_SESSION["s_order"] = "ASC";
$order = $_SESSION["s_order"];
$sort = $_SESSION["s_sort"];


if($admin && $action == "del" && id != "") {
    $tObj = new Test($id);
    $tObj->remove();
}


$tObj = new Test();
$res = $tObj->getOverview($sort." ".$order);
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/bg.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="js/tooltip.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function delTest(id, name) {
        var check = window.confirm("Are you sure you want to remove the entire test ("+name+")?");
        if(check) location.href = "?action=del&id="+id;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<? require_once "navigation/pagehead.php"; ?>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="20" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><a href="tests.php" class="breadcumbs">Tests overview </a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><? if($admin) { ?><a href="test_detail.php?action=new">&raquo; create new test <img src="pix/new.gif" width="14" height="14" border="0" alt="view"></a><? } ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="2" border="0" class="datatable">
    <tr>
        <th><a href="?sort=name">name<? if($sort=="name") { ?>&nbsp;<img src="<? if($order == "ASC") echo "pix/ascending.gif"; else echo "pix/descending.gif"; ?>" width="9" height="7" border="0" alt="view"><? } ?></a></th>
        <th><a href="?sort=description">description<? if($sort=="description") { ?>&nbsp;<img src="<? if($order == "ASC") echo "pix/ascending.gif"; else echo "pix/descending.gif"; ?>" width="9" height="7" border="0" alt="view"><? } ?></a></th>
        <th><a href="?sort=created">created<? if($sort=="created") { ?>&nbsp;<img src="<? if($order == "ASC") echo "pix/ascending.gif"; else echo "pix/descending.gif"; ?>" width="9" height="7" border="0" alt="view"><? } ?></a></th>
        <th><a href="?sort=last_modified">last modified<? if($sort=="last_modified") { ?>&nbsp;<img src="<? if($order == "ASC") echo "pix/ascending.gif"; else echo "pix/descending.gif"; ?>" border="0" width="9" height="7" alt="view"><? } ?></a></th>
        <th><a href="?sort=run_count">runs<? if($sort=="run_count") { ?>&nbsp;<img src="<? if($order == "ASC") echo "pix/ascending.gif"; else echo "pix/descending.gif"; ?>" border="0" width="9" height="7" alt="view"><? } ?></a></th>
        <? if($admin) { ?>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <? } ?>
    </tr>
    <?
    $even = true;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($res)) {
    if($even) $bgcol = "#EEEEEE";
    else $bgcol = "#DDDDDD";
    ?>
    <tr style="background-color:<? echo $bgcol; ?>;" onMouseOver="this.style.background='#B9FAFD'" onMouseOut="this.style.background='<? echo $bgcol; ?>'">
        <td onClick="location.href='test_detail.php?version=-1&id=<? echo $row->id; ?>'"><? echo $row->name; ?></td>
        <td onClick="location.href='test_detail.php?version=-1&id=<? echo $row->id; ?>'"><? echo shorten($row->description, 40); ?></td>
        <td align="center" onClick="location.href='test_detail.php?version=-1&id=<? echo $row->id; ?>'"><? echo $row->created; ?></td>
        <td align="center" onClick="location.href='test_detail.php?version=-1&id=<? echo $row->id; ?>'"><? echo $row->last_modified; ?></td>
        <td align="center" onClick="location.href='test_detail.php?version=-1&id=<? echo $row->id; ?>'"><? echo $row->run_count; ?></td>
        <? if($admin) { ?>
        <td align="center"><a href="javascript: delTest(<? echo $row->id; ?>, '<? echo $row->name; ?>')"><img src="pix/del.gif" width="14" height="14" border="0" alt="remove"></a></td>
        <? } ?>
    </tr>
    <? 
    $even = !$even;
    } 
    ?>
  </table>
    </td></tr>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the code for that file?

Comment: Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Modify php.ini with the change: `short_open_tag = On`

Comment: For PHP5 the `php.ini` file is located here: `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`. You will need to restart apache with: `sudo service apache2 restart`